# C# SQL to Linq - translation

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with transactions, similar to:

```
--REQUEST_ID----ITEM_ID----ITEM_STATUS_CD----EXECUTION_DTTM       
     1             1            1          2016-08-29 12:36:07.000   
     1             2            0          2016-08-29 12:37:07.000
     2             3            5          2016-08-29 13:37:07.000
     2             4            1          2016-08-29 15:37:07.000
     2             5            10         2016-08-29 15:41:07.000
     3             6            0          2016-08-29 15:41:07.000
```

What i want is at table showing how many success/warning/Error in % with endtime of the latest transaction in the Request_ID:

```
--REQUEST_ID--Transactions----------EndTime----------Success----Warning----Error     
     1               2        2016-08-29 12:37:07.000   50         50         0
     2               3        2016-08-29 15:41:07.000    0         33         66
     3               1        2016-08-29 15:41:07.000   100         0         0
```

I have the table that I want by the following slq, but I dont know how to do it in linq(C#)....Anyone?

```
SELECT distinct t1.[REQUEST_ID], 
              t2.Transactions,
              t2.EndTime,
              t2.Success,
              t2.Warning,
              t2.Error
          FROM [dbo].[jp_R_ITEM] t1 inner join(
          select top(100) max([EXECUTION_DTTM]) EndTime,  REQUEST_ID,
                 count([ITEM_ID]) as Transactions,
                 coalesce(count(case when [ITEM_STATUS_CD] = 0 then 1 end), 0) * 100 / count([ITEM_ID]) as Success,
                 coalesce(count(case when [ITEM_STATUS_CD] = 1 then 1 end), 0) * 100 / count([ITEM_ID]) as Warning,
                 coalesce(count(case when [ITEM_STATUS_CD] > 1 then 1 end), 0) * 100 / count([ITEM_ID]) as Error
            from  [dbo].[jp_R_ITEM] group by REQUEST_ID order by REQUEST_ID desc) t2 on t1.[REQUEST_ID] = t2.REQUEST_ID and t1.[EXECUTION_DTTM] = t2.EndTime
```

Comment: Don't. Build a proper entity model, add proper relations and navigation properties and you *won't* have to care about translation. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL

Comment: If you want to create a report, *don't* try to do it with LINQ. Create a view and map your reporting entities to it. Create reporting tables that make reporting easier and fill them from the transactional data.

Comment: BTW you should probably explain what you want to produce from that query. You may be able to simplify it by using windowing functions, or use PIVOT to calculate counts per `ITEM_STATUS_CD`. That `TOP(100)` looks weird too. Why pick the first 100 requests by ID only?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I am new to Entity model - asp.net mvc, but i tried to use it and it worked fine on my test-table. But my problem is, that I have one main table (like the transactions table above) and i wanted to create sql view's on that table to create graphs/charts in google charts (a dashboard), but then I found out that entity framework isn't suitable for sql views... Any advise ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from t1 in lst
                     join t2 in (from b in lst
                                 group b by b.REQUEST_ID into grp
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     EndTime = (from g1 in grp select g1.EXECUTION_DTTM).Max(),
                                     REQUEST_ID = grp.Key,
                                     Transactions = grp.Count(),
                                     Success = ((from g2 in grp select g2.ITEM_STATUS_CD).Count(x => x == 0)) * 100 / grp.Count(),
                                     Warning = ((from g3 in grp select g3.ITEM_STATUS_CD).Count(x => x == 1)) * 100 / grp.Count(),
                                     Error = ((from g4 in grp select g4.ITEM_STATUS_CD).Count(x => x > 1)) * 100 / grp.Count(),
                                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.REQUEST_ID).Take(100)
                     on new { RID = t1.REQUEST_ID, EXDT = t1.EXECUTION_DTTM } equals new { RID = t2.REQUEST_ID, EXDT = t2.EndTime }
                     select new
                     {
                         t1.REQUEST_ID,
                         t2.Transactions,
                         t2.EndTime,
                         t2.Success,
                         t2.Warning,
                         t2.Error
                     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: worked perfectly :) But now i trying something else - I don't want to Take(100) rows and the order by Request_ID as previously - but take the 100 last rows in the table and the order by Request_ID....Any solution ?

Comment: I think you can `OrderByDescending(x => x.REQUEST_ID)` then `Take(100)`

Answer (score 0):

So from all your `Transactions` with `RequestId` 1, you want to make one element. This one element should have the `RequestId`, which in this case is 1, it should have the latest value of all `ExecutionDttms` or transactions with `RequestId`, and finally, from all those transaction you want a percentage of successes, warnings and errors

You want something similar for the Transactions with RequestId 2, and for the Transactions with RequestId 3, etc.

> Whenever you see something like: "I want to group all items from a sequence into one object" you should immediately think of GroupBy.

This one object might be a very complex object, a List, a Dictionary, or an object of a class with a lot of properties

So let's first make groups of Transactions that have the same RequestId:

```
var groupsWithSameRequestId = Transactions
    .GroupBy(transaction => transaction.RequestId);
```

Every group has a `Key`, which is the `RequestId` of all elements in the Group. Every group **is** (not has) the sequence of all Transaction that have this `RequestId` value.

You want to transform every group into one result element. Every result element
has a property `RequestId` and the number of transactions with this `RequestId`.

The `RequestId` is the `Key` of the group, the `TransactionCount` is of course the number of elements in the group

```
var result = groupsWithSameRequestId.Select(group => new
{
    RequestId = group.Key,
    TransactionCount = group.Count(),
    ...
};
```

Those were the easiest ones.

Endtime is the maximum value of all ExecutionDttm in your group.

```
 var result = groupsWithSameRequestId.Select(group => new
{
    RequestId = group.Key,
    TransactionCount = group.Count(),
    EndTime = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.ExecutionDttm).Max(),
    ...
};
```

It might be that your data query translator does not allow to Max on Datetime. In that case: order descending and take the first:

```
EndTime = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.ExecutionDttm)
    .OrderByDescenting(date => date)
    .First(),
```

`First()` is enough, `FirstOrDefault()` is not needed, we know there are no groups without any elements

We have save the most difficult / fun part for the last. You want the percentage  of success / warning / errors, which is the number of elements with `ItemStatus` 0 / 1 / more.

```
Success = 100 * group
    .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus == 0).Count()
    /group.Count(),
Warning = 100 * group
    .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus == 1).Count()
    /group.Count(),
Error = 100 * group
    .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus > 1).Count()
    /group.Count(),
```

It depends a bit on how smart your IQueryable / DbContext is. But at first glance it seems that Count() is called quite often. Introducing an extra `Select` will prevent this.

So combining this all into one LINQ statement:

```
var result = Transactions
    .GroupBy(transaction => transaction.RequestId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        RequestId = group.Key
        GroupCount = group.Count(),
        SuccessCount = group
            .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus == 0).Count(),
        WarningCount = group
            .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus == 1).Count(),
        ErrorCount = group
            .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ItemStatus > 1).Count(),

        EndTime = group
            .Select(groupElement => groupElement.ExecutionDttm)
            .Max(),
     })
     .Select(item => new
     {
         RequestId = item.RequestId,
         TransactionCount = item.GroupCount,

         EndTime = item.EndTime,

         SuccessCount = 100.0 * item.SuccesCount / item.GroupCount,
         WarningCount = 100.0 * item.WarningCount / item.GroupCount,
         ErrorCount = 100.0 * item.ErrorCount / item.GroupCount,
     }
```